# Style cell in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render

I format column in jTable, but style value column `STT` change not like value in column `Loại Nhân Viên`, column `STT` change than default.

[image]

Code to format column `STT`

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer();
cellRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` instead of a `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer` (which is not in the public API anyway, and probably shouldn't be used).

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
cellRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
```

Comment: @NguyenNhu Pls accept the answer if your problem is solved .. :)